# Ruby Built In Method to Create Multidimensional Array From Single Dimensioned Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, idioms

If I have an array like this: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, is there a built in method to create this:
`[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]` given a width of 3? If there is no built in method, how could I improve on this?

```
def multi_to_single(array, width)
    return [].tap{|md_array|
        (array.length.to_f / width).ceil.times {|y|
            row = (array[(y*width), width])
            md_array.push( row + Array.new(width - row.length))
        }
    }
end
```

I feel like I have missed something obvious because I haven't programmed ruby in a while!
Thanks in advance, ell.

EDIT: It needs to be in the core library, so no ruby on rails or anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

`[1,2,3,4,5,6].each_slice(3).to_a #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`

Using ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365)

Comment: That's also pretty much how in_groups_of is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [in_groups_of](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html#M000833) method in Rails which is designed to solve this problem !

Comment: This is very good although I'm looking for something in the core library, I will edit my question to clarify this. Although looking at the source is useful!

Comment: It doesn't exist in the core library directly I think.

Comment: It doesn't exist? Okay I will mark your answer as correct then after leaving this question open for a while to see if anyone else answers.

Comment: I think if Rails developers implemented it, it's because it was missing in core.

Comment: @Ell: Use the implementation for in_groups_of. The source code is listed in the link above by Skydreamer. I see no dependencies on the other Rails libs and it is simpler and more efficient than your attempt.

Comment: I think Kai's implementation is significantly simpler than either of the others